# Available & Most Profitable Ad System for iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, ads

After release my first iPhone application I had a fairly decent turnover in turns of sales considering it was a pretty niche application in the health and fitness category.  However, I decided to make the application free until the next update and in the first 3 days downloads of my app have increased by 1433% - which is quite staggering.

So it got me thinking maybe the option of a free application, with ads would be a better option.  With that said, what are the available options for integrating ads into an iPhone app and which is the most profitable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iAD is the most profitable as it pays lot per impression, but they don't always fill the slot. The best thing you can do is to implement some service like [AdWhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/) which will fill the empty slot with another service such as JumpTap or Admob when the iAd slot does not come through. You can adjust the frequency of each ad network to your liking as well, so if later, you decide that JumpTap should be shown always, you can adjust it from the web interface instead of pushing a new version of your app.

Comment: I have noticed on a few apps that I use that the iAd space is now filled with 'Test Advertisement' - haven't seen an actual ad for a long time. I'll look into the other suggestion you mentioned, thanks

Comment: Test Advertisement is shown on iOS Beta Devices. As a developer, you probably have iOS 5 installed, thus Test Advertisement is shown

Comment: Test Advertisement is shown for developers only (so devs can't cheat ad impressions on their own apps). It doesn't reflect the actual filtrate of the network.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use iAds now that Apple has prevented other ad networks from device-tracking.

Comment: Apple lifted the restrictions they placed on these ad networks, a month after they were put in place last year.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware of that. But how about this then : http://veryrite.com/2011/08/20/apple-to-block-developers-access-to-uuid-in-ios-5/

Comment: This is different, and technically not supposed to be talked about (iOS5). But still, the lack of a UUID will not stop advertising tracking.